# Something blocking Open Graph on my server?

Tags: wordpress, facebook-opengraph

I've got a problem. My web-site is working with wordpress.

When i'm trying to [debug](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://nuzhnapomosh.ru/) it, i've got an error: Could not retrieve data from URL. 
But when i'm trying to [debug the HTML page](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://nuzhnapomosh.ru/og.html)everything works well.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

your page is loading hard, the only difference i see between you homepage and og.html is that on homepage you didn't add **og:url**
I'm not sure but after a little googleing russian seems to be **ISO-8859-5** not **utf-8** at the charset [w3schools Charsets](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_charactersets.asp)